# Complex powers of unity. What are possible values of 1^a?

Tags: complex-analysis

Okay, here's the question as printed: What are the possible values of $1^a$?

Aaand here's my issue... It was never stated whether $a \in \mathbb{R}$ or $a \in \mathbb{C}$.

I find the image of $1^a ,a \in \mathbb{R}$ gives the complex unit circle, which makes sense to me. If $a$ is an integer, we find that $1^a = 1$ as expected, but any nonintegral value delivers a rotation.

But I didn't anticipate the image of $1^a, a \in \mathbb{C}$. Is it really $\mathbb{C} \setminus\{0\}$ ??

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the answers. What an interesting result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing
$$ 1 = e^{2\pi n i}, $$
where $n$ is an integer, you have for $n \neq 0$
$$ 1^a = e^{2\pi n a i}, $$
which does only miss one point of $\mathbb{C}$, zero.

However, you can always choose a branch of the $()^a$ function that has $1^a=1$ (by setting $n=0$).

Answer (score 1):

let $z=a+ib$ where a and b are real.

Then $1^z = e^{2\pi i (a+ib)} = e^{-2 \pi b} e^{i 2 \pi a }$

so it can have any phase and any modulus except zero